# Haskell measuring function performance

Tags: haskell, profiling, benchmarking

In Haskell, how can i 'simply' measure a functions performance. For example, how long it takes to run, or how much memory it takes?. I am aware of profiling, however, is there a more simple way that will not require me to change my code too much?

Comment: Try to set `:set +s` in GHCI and call your function. But this still does not show you how much time was spent in the function ifself, not in functions called by it.

Comment: How does profiling require you to change your code? [Criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) is a nice library for performance measurements

Comment: How can i use profiling to measure a function performance?. This doesnt require code changes? A change to 'ghc +RTS -s -RTS -O2 -prof -auto-all Main.hs' ?

Comment: @user2214957 How is setting a compiler option a code change?

Comment: compile with `-O2`, run with `+RTS -s`, be sure to measure [empirical_orders_of_growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) for your algorithm.

Answer (score 18):

Measuring how long it takes to run and how much memory it takes are two separate problems, namely: benchmarking and profiling. Haskell has a well defined set of tools for both. Solving neither of the problems requires you to make any changes to the actual application's code.

### Benchmarking

This is done using libraries. There is an ultimate winner in that area, which was suggested by Niklas in the comments, namely [**Criterion**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion). The library is very well designed, isn't hard to use and produces a [very detailed data](http://bos.github.com/criterion/).

The workflow is the following: you create a separate module containing the setup of your benchmark, compile it and run it with options. To get a reference on available options run it with `--help` modifier.

You can find examples of setup modules [here](https://github.com/bos/criterion/tree/master/examples).

### Profiling

There is enough of good materials on that already, so I'll just refer to them:

- [General reference on profiling](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/profiling.html)
- [A tutorial in Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html)
- [A tutorial on profiling with Cabal](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_profile_a_Haskell_program)

Answer (score 11):

For extremely crude information on how individual functions perform compared to each other, you can use ghci

```
Prelude> :set +s
Prelude> last [1..100000000]
100000000
(1.65 secs, 4000685276 bytes)
```

You need to be aware that ghci doesn't compile code, so runs *much* slower than ghc, the timing and memory usage data is approximate, and that absolutely no optimisation has been performed.

This means that it gives you only a very rough idea of how (in)efficient your code is, and is no substitute for proper benchmarking and profiling of compiled and optimised code, as detailed in [Nikita Volkov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15765060/1598537).

Comment: I have to disagree with this suggestion; if the code is meant to run as a compiled program, how it performs in ghci can be profoundly misleading.  My favorite example is that I've gotten cases where a program that works fine in ghci will produce a stack overflow when compiled, when applied to the same input.

Comment: @sacundim Good example, thanks. I called it "extremely crude" for that reason. I've added more caveats at the end. This answer's here to point out a quick-and-rough option, not to replace proper metrics.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of the "extremely crude," but I still feel that it's likely to mislead. My example, I think, speaks for itself.

Comment: if GHCi is started with `-fobject-code` option, or `*Main> :set -fobject-code` is entered at the REPL, then it will compile any file on load. But, though I'm not sure, I think it uses `-O` always (not `-O2)`. It will be a bit less misleading that way. Even though it's compiled, when run as standalone executable, the results can too be wildly different, esp. w.r.t. memory usage. I've seen code that runs in constant space standalone, consume hundreds of megabytes when loaded (compiled, even with -O2) into GHCi. :)